# Iphone X notch size in an opengl app?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, iphone-x

I have a fullscreen game that uses GLKView, so no layouts or stuff like that, and I don't understand how do I get Iphone X notch size or safe area size to position my game objects/ui correctly.

Currently I just hardcoded the notch size, but that is definitely not right.
I tried to get **safeAreaInsets** from the **keyWindow** or **safeAreaLayoutGuide** but it is always zero for some reason.

What should I do? Is there a way to get the safe area size or the notch size in pixels/points without using layouts for a fullscreen app?